# Why are bitfields not allowed in OpenCL?

Tags: opencl, bit-fields

Bitfields are not supported in the OpenCL language. What was the reason to not support them? Unlike in other pieces omited (recursion, pointers to functions, ...), where there is an obvious reason to not support them, I fail to see one for bitfields. I am sure that it is not an oversight on behalf of the commitee, but what is the reason?

(I store some bits packed in ints, and the code would be nicer to read with them. I understand bitfields as nice syntax for avoiding bit-shifting and masking back and forth, which is what they translate to in assembly anyway.)

Answer (score 9):

I was able to ask this question of somebody involved in the working group.  Here's what he had to say:

> Bit-fields are not portable -- so they could not
>   be used in types used for kernel arguments.
>
> The only place they *could* be used is for types for local variables
>   declared inside a kernel.
>
> The OpenCL working group was not convinced this was very useful.  In
>   addition, there were concerns that compilers may not generate
>   efficient code when using bitfields.  All of these led the
>   working group to the decision not to support bit-fields in OpenCL C.

Comment: It's important to remember that OpenCL allows for things like a little-endian host and a big-endian device. Allowing bit-fields would only serve to further complicate mixed-endianness support.

Comment: Not portable... the argument it works only with the same endianness is weak. Many OpenCL codes (mine included) will be written for a specific hardware. The programmer should know better what to use and what not. (I have piece of code to access groups of bits within an int; it would be so much easier with bitfields :-| )

Answer (score 1):

Wikipedia has some info on the [drawbacks of bitfields](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bit_field#Drawbacks_of_the_structure-based_approach):

> Bit members in structures as presented above have potential practical drawbacks. First, the ordering of bits in memory is CPU dependent and memory padding rules can vary between compilers. In addition, less well-optimized compilers sometimes generate poor quality code for reading and writing bit members and there are potentially thread safety issues relating to bit fields because most machines cannot manipulate arbitrary sets of bits in memory, but must instead load and store whole words.

I think all of these drawbacks are relevant in an OpenCL environment.

Comment: OpenCL types have (in conforming implementation) the same memory layout, otherwise copying buffers from host to device would make no sense. Point taken for bits ordering. For the rest (thread safety, compiler quality), that is no different from CPUs. I could paste my code for bitfields packed in ints: it is extremely inelegant.

Comment: Presumably, endianness only affects arrays of longs and so on?  If we store/send as an array of unsigned chars, then the ordering of the bytes, and the ordering of the bits within the bytes, is guaranteed?